# Pandas - generar dos registros para un evento

Tags: pandas

Buena tarde comunidad.

Les comento, en mi trabajo están trabajando en excel unos registros, pero muchas modificaciones las hacen manuales.
Y yo estoy intentando hacerlo con pandas para tratar de automatizar esa parte.

Ejemplo:

- Un registro que empieza en un día y termina en otro.

  [image: 2022-10-01 23:56:00, 2022-10-02 03:02:00]
- Deseo lo siguiente que ese registro por de decirlo de una forma se duplique pero generando lo siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco desde ya su apoyo.

Comment: a ver si entiendo, quieres que se divida el registro en partes?

Comment: Sí, porque el registro de una ‘alarma’  empezó el día 1 pero continuó hasta el día dos, pero necesito tener los dos registros desde que empezó y que se pare al terminar el día y el siguiente empiece a las 0 horas hasta que haya terminado la ‘alarma’.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Gracias por tu observación, tienes razón no es muy clara la explicación, edité el problema para que se pueda entender de mejor manera, gracias.